# Change language of screen reader in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, accessibility, uiaccessibility

I'm using Accessibility API in react-native, and I wish to change the language of screen readers like VoiceOver (iOS) and TalkBack (Android) when the user has changed the language.

Can someone please guide me with this?

***PS:*** I've tried using `accessibilityLanguage` prop in react-native but it isn't working

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The lang attribute on `<html>` or `<body>` should normally work including when changing it dynamically. Doesn't it ? You need, of course, to install a voice in the language you want to use, and enable language auto-detection.

Comment: @QuentinC how about doing this in Android or iOS, using react-native?

Comment: I don't know react, sorry. But it shouldn't be difficult to change an attribute. Vanilla js: `document.body.setAttribute('lang', 'fr');` to set French for example.